# How to understand LSTM performance generated on a graph?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, keras, nlp, data-science

I used LSTM by applying Keras for the task of Named Entity Recognition. The model present around 95% accuracy. Then I tried to create the graph for accuracy and loss. Now I do know, what do these two graphs present?

[image]

[image]